# Find a class somewhere inside dozens of JAR files?

Tags: java, class, jar, project-structure, text-search

How would you find a particular class name inside lots of jar files?

(Looking for the actual class name, not the classes that reference it.)

Comment: I don't know about any of these answers, but what works for me if you see the class used in a working project with numerous JAR files is to put your cursor on the class name, right click on it, and click Open Declaration (F3); then it should list the JAR file at the top of the new tab.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Eclipse can do it, just create a (temporary) project and put your libraries on the projects classpath. Then you can easily find the classes.

Another tool, that comes to my mind, is Java Decompiler. It can open a lot of jars at once and helps to find classes as well.

Comment: and with the help of Ctrl + Shift + T

Answer (score 512):

## Unix

On Linux, other Unix variants, Git Bash on Windows, or Cygwin, use the `jar` (or `unzip -v`), `grep`, and `find` commands.

The following lists all class files that match a given name:

```bash
for i in *.jar; do jar -tvf "$i" | grep -Hsi ClassName && echo "$i"; done
```

If you know the entire list of Java archives you want to search, you could place them all in the same directory using (symbolic) links.

Or use `find` (case sensitively) to find the JAR file that contains a given class name:

```bash
find path/to/libs -name '*.jar' -exec grep -Hls ClassName {} \;
```

For example, to find the name of the archive containing `IdentityHashingStrategy`:

```bash
$ find . -name '*.jar' -exec grep -Hsli IdentityHashingStrategy {} \;
./trove-3.0.3.jar
```

If the JAR could be *anywhere* in the system and the [`locate`](http://www.linfo.org/locate.html) command is available:

```bash
for i in $(locate "*.jar");
  do echo "$i"; jar -tvf "$i" | grep -Hsi ClassName;
done
```

A syntax variation:

```bash
find path/to/libs -name '*.jar' -print | \
  while read i; do jar -tvf "$i" | grep -Hsi ClassName && echo "$i"; done
```

## Windows

Open a [command prompt](https://conemu.github.io/), change to the directory (or ancestor directory) containing the JAR files, then:

```
for /R %G in (*.jar) do @jar -tvf "%G" | find "ClassName" > NUL && echo %G
```

Here's how it works:

1. `for /R %G in (*.jar) do` - loop over all JAR files, recursively traversing directories; store the file name in `%G`.
2. `@jar -tvf "%G" |` - run the Java Archive command to list all file names within the given archive, and write the results to standard output; the `@` symbol suppresses printing the command's invocation.
3. `find "ClassName" > NUL` - search standard input, piped from the output of the jar command, for the given class name; this will set `ERRORLEVEL` to 1 iff there's a match (otherwise 0).
4. `&& echo %G` - iff `ERRORLEVEL` is non-zero, write the Java archive file name to standard output (the console).

## Web

Use a [search engine](https://www.google.ca/search?q=JAR+search+engine) that scans JAR files.

Answer (score 66):

some time ago, I wrote a program just for that: https://github.com/javalite/jar-explorer

Comment: Finds any type of file, not just classes. Double-click to see file contents. Yay, now I can spot all my spring-schemas.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 35):

```
grep -l "classname" *.jar
```

gives you the name of the jar

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec jar -t -f {} \; | grep  "classname"
```

gives you the package of the class

Comment: It should be grep -lir "classname" *.jar

Answer (score 13):

```
#!/bin/bash

pattern=$1
shift

for jar in $(find $* -type f -name "*.jar")
do
  match=`jar -tvf $jar | grep $pattern`
  if [ ! -z "$match" ]
  then
    echo "Found in: $jar"
    echo "$match"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Great ! I had to use it on a system that didn't have jar (not in the path, that is), so I replaced `jar -tvf` with `unzip -l`.

Answer (score 9):

To locate jars that match a given string:

`find . -name \*.jar -exec grep -l YOUR_CLASSNAME {} \;`

Comment: This finds references to the class as well, not just the class itself.

Answer (score 8):

I didn't know of a utility to do it when I came across this problem, so I wrote the following:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static String CLASS_FILE_TO_FIND =
            "class.to.find.Here";
    private static List<String> foundIn = new LinkedList<String>();

    /**
     * @param args the first argument is the path of the file to search in. The second may be the
     *        class file to find.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (!CLASS_FILE_TO_FIND.endsWith(".class")) {
            CLASS_FILE_TO_FIND = CLASS_FILE_TO_FIND.replace('.', '/') + ".class";
        }
        File start = new File(args[0]);
        if (args.length > 1) {
            CLASS_FILE_TO_FIND = args[1];
        }
        search(start);
        System.out.println("------RESULTS------");
        for (String s : foundIn) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    private static void search(File start) {
        try {
            final FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {

                public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                    return pathname.getName().endsWith(".jar") || pathname.isDirectory();
                }
            };
            for (File f : start.listFiles(filter)) {
                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                    search(f);
                } else {
                    searchJar(f);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error at: " + start.getPath() + " " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void searchJar(File f) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Searching: " + f.getPath());
            JarFile jar = new JarFile(f);
            ZipEntry e = jar.getEntry(CLASS_FILE_TO_FIND);
            if (e == null) {
                e = jar.getJarEntry(CLASS_FILE_TO_FIND);
                if (e != null) {
                    foundIn.add(f.getPath());
                }
            } else {
                foundIn.add(f.getPath());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

There are also two different utilities called both "JarScan" that do exactly what you are asking for:
[JarScan (inetfeedback.com)](http://www.inetfeedback.com/jarscan/) and [JarScan (java.net)](http://java.net/projects/jarscan)

Answer (score 6):

ClassFinder is a program that's designed to solve this problem. It allows you to search recursively through directories and jar files to find all instances of a class matching a pattern. It is written in Java, not python. It has a nice GUI which makes it easy to use. And it runs fast. This release is precompiled in a runnable jar so you don't have to build it from source.

Download it here: [ClassFinder 1.0](https://github.com/gungwald/classfinder/releases)

Answer (score 4):

user1207523's script works fine for me. Here is a variant that searches for jar files recusively using find instead of simple expansion;

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `find . -name '*.jar'`; do jar -tf "$i" | grep $1 | xargs -I{} echo -e "$i : {}" ; done
```

Answer (score 4):

I've always used this on Windows and its worked exceptionally well.

```
findstr /s /m /c:"package/classname" *.jar, where
```

findstr.exe comes standard with Windows and the params:

- /s = recursively
- /m = print only the filename if there is a match
- /c = literal string (in this case your package name + class names
  separated by '/')

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

A `bash script` solution using `unzip (zipinfo)`. Tested on `Ubuntu 12`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# ./jarwalker.sh "/a/Starting/Path" "aClassName"

IFS=$'\n'
jars=( $( find -P "$1" -type f -name "*.jar" ) )

for jar in ${jars[*]}
    do
        classes=( $( zipinfo -1 ${jar} | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' | grep .class | awk -F '.' '{print $1}' ) )
        if [ ${#classes[*]} -ge 0 ]; then
            for class in ${classes[*]}
                do
                    if [ ${class} == "$2" ]; then
                        echo "Found in ${jar}"
                    fi
                done
        fi
    done
```

Comment: this script is not mingw compatible

Answer (score 3):

To find a class in a folder (and subfolders) bunch of JARs:
https://jarscan.com/

```
Usage: java -jar jarscan.jar [-help | /?]
                    [-dir directory name]
                    [-zip]
                    [-showProgress]
                    <-files | -class | -package>
                    <search string 1> [search string 2]
                    [search string n]

Help:
  -help or /?           Displays this message.

  -dir                  The directory to start searching
                        from default is "."

  -zip                  Also search Zip files

  -showProgress         Show a running count of files read in

  -files or -class      Search for a file or Java class
                        contained in some library.
                        i.e. HttpServlet

  -package              Search for a Java package
                        contained in some library.
                        i.e. javax.servlet.http

  search string         The file or package to
                        search for.
                        i.e. see examples above
```

**Example:**

```
java -jar jarscan.jar -dir C:\Folder\To\Search -showProgress -class GenericServlet
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use FindClassInJars util, it's a simple swing program, but useful. You can check source code or download jar file at http://code.google.com/p/find-class-in-jars/

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but nevertheless...

I've been using [JarBrowser](http://jarbrowser.sourceforge.net/) to find in which jar a particular class is present.  It's got an easy to use GUI which allows you to browse through the contents of all the jars in the selected path.

Answer (score 2):

To search all jar files in a given directory for a particular class, you can do this:

```
ls *.jar | xargs grep -F MyClass
```

or, even simpler,

```
grep -F MyClass *.jar
```

Output looks like this:

```
Binary file foo.jar matches
```

It's very fast because the -F option means search for Fixed string, so it doesn't load the the regex engine for each grep invocation.  If you need to, you can always omit the -F option and use regexes.

Answer (score 2):

To add yet another tool... this is a very simple and useful tool for windows. A simple exe file you click on, give it a directory to search in, a class name and it will find the jar file that contains that class. Yes, it's recursive.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jarfinder/

Answer (score 2):

I found this new way

```
bash $ ls -1  | xargs -i -t jar -tvf '{}'| grep Abstract
jar -tvf activation-1.1.jar
jar -tvf antisamy-1.4.3.jar
  2263 Thu Jan 13 21:38:10 IST 2011 org/owasp/validator/html/scan/AbstractAntiSamyScanner.class
...
```

So this lists the jar and the class if found, if you want you can give ls -1 *.jar or input to xargs with find command HTH Someone.

Comment: Thanks, I improve it this way : ls -1 *.jar  | xargs -i -t jar -tvf '{}'| grep Abstract

Answer (score 1):

Check JBoss [Tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale); although I've never used it personally, this seems to be the tool you need.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why scripts here have never really worked for me. This works:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.jar; do jar -tf "$i" | grep $1 | xargs -I{} echo -e "$i : {}" ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Script to find jar file: find_jar.sh

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") # Set the field separator newline

for f in `find ${1} -iname *.jar`; do
  jar -tf ${f}| grep --color $2
  if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo -n "Match found: "
    echo -e "${f}\n"
  fi
done
unset IFS
```

Usage: ./find_jar.sh < top-level directory containing jar files > < Class name to find>

This is similar to most answers given here. But it only outputs the file name, if grep finds something. If you want to suppress grep output you may redirect that to /dev/null but I prefer seeing the output of grep as well so that I can use partial class names and figure out the correct one from a list of output shown.

The class name can be both simple class name Like "String" or fully qualified name like "java.lang.String"

Answer (score 1):

Filename: searchForFiles.py

```
import os, zipfile, glob, sys

def main():
    searchFile = sys.argv[1] #class file to search for, sent from batch file below (optional, see second block of code below)
    listOfFilesInJar = []
    for file in glob.glob("*.jar"):
        archive = zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r')
        for x in archive.namelist():
            if str(searchFile) in str(x):
                listOfFilesInJar.append(file)

    for something in listOfFilesInJar:
        print("location of "+str(searchFile)+": ",something)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

You can easily run this by making a .bat file with the following text (replace "AddWorkflows.class" with the file you are searching for):

(File: CallSearchForFiles.bat)

```
@echo off
python -B -c "import searchForFiles;x=searchForFiles.main();" AddWorkflows.class
pause
```

You can double-click CallSearchForFiles.bat to run it, or call it from the command line "CallSearchForFiles.bat SearchFile.class"

[Click to See Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0KUd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a class in a directory full of jars with a bit of shell:

Looking for class "FooBar":

```
LIB_DIR=/some/dir/full/of/jarfiles
for jarfile in $(find $LIBDIR -name "*.jar"); do
   echo "--------$jarfile---------------"
   jar -tvf $jarfile | grep FooBar
done
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add to all of the above: if you don't have the jar executable available (it comes with the JDK but not with the JRE), you can use unzip (or WinZip, or whatever) to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

shameless self promotion, but you can try a utility I wrote : http://sourceforge.net/projects/zfind

It supports most common archive/compressed files (jar, zip, tar, tar.gz etc) and unlike many other jar/zip finders, supports nested zip files (zip within zip, jar within jar etc) till unlimited depth.

Answer (score 0):

Following script will help you out

```sh
for file in *.jar
do
  # do something on "$file"
  echo "$file"
  /usr/local/jdk/bin/jar -tvf "$file" | grep '$CLASSNAME'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works well in MinGW ( windows bash environment ) ~ gitbash

Put this function into your .bashrc file in your HOME directory:

```
# this function helps you to find a jar file for the class
function find_jar_of_class() {
  OLD_IFS=$IFS
  IFS=$'\n'
  jars=( $( find -type f -name "*.jar" ) )
  for i in ${jars[*]} ; do 
    if [ ! -z "$(jar -tvf "$i" | grep -Hsi $1)" ] ; then
      echo "$i"
    fi
   done 
  IFS=$OLD_IFS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Grepj](https://github.com/rrevo/grepj) is a command line utility to search for classes within jar files. I am the author of the utility.

You can run the utility like `grepj package.Class my1.jar my2.war my3.ear`

Multiple jar, ear, war files can be provided. For advanced usage use find to provide a list of jars to be searched.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Plugin for eclipse which can do the job you are looking for.

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jarchiveexplorer

Answer (score 0):

Under a Linux environment you could do the following :

```
$ find <base_dir> -name *.jar -print0 | xargs -0 -l jar tf | grep <name>
```

Where ***name*** is the name of the class file that you are looking inside the jars distributed across the hierarchy of directories rooted at the ***base_dir***.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locate` and `grep`:

```
locate jar | xargs grep 'my.class'
```

Make sure you run `updatedb` before using `locate`.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse you can use the old but still usable plugin [jarsearch](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jarsearch/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of the class, or can get one, you have a pure java solution:

```
try{
    Class clazz = Class.forName("        try{
        Class clazz = Class.forName("class-name");
        String name = "/"+clazz.getName().replace('.', '/')+".class";
        URL url = clazz.getResource(name);
        String jar = url.toString().substring(10).replaceAll("!.*", "");
        System.out.println( jar );
    }catch(Exception err){
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Of course, the first two line have to adapted according to where you have an instance of the class or the class name.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but...
I had the same issue, so If someone is looking for a very simple solution for windows - there is a software named Locate32
Just put jar as file extension
And containing the class name
It finds the file within seconds.

[image: Locate32 in action]

Answer (score -1):

Use this.. you can find any file in classpath.. guaranteed..

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class FileFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String file = <your file name>;

        ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

        for(URL url: urls){
            listFiles(file, url);
        }
    }

    private static void listFiles(String file, URL url) throws Exception{
        ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(url.openStream());
          while(true) {
            ZipEntry e = zip.getNextEntry();
            if (e == null)
              break;
            String name = e.getName();
            if (name.endsWith(file)) {
                System.out.println(url.toString() + " -> " + name);
            }
          }
    }

}
```