# How to add external jar...through URL..using .classpath?

Tags: eclipse

**In any javaProject in eclipse there we always get .classpath file...like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry path="ABC/junit" kind="src"/>
    <classpathentry path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER" kind="con"/>
    <classpathentry path="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4" kind="con"/>
    <classpathentry path="targets" kind="output"/>
</classpath>
```

Here when we import any external jar it is giving path of that jar in classpathentry...i want that classpathentry should be from any URL
which will provide that external jar...can anyone plz tell me how to do that..actually i want to add external jar automatically from URL(any)
when user will import that project in eclipse..i don't want user will manually add external jars..i want to make change .classpath accordingly. Or anyother way to do this automatically. Please help me...Waiting for reply.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That way of adding dependencies is better managed by **maven**, with [**m2eclipse**](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/)

Of you configure your [Eclipse Build Path to use Maven dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037188/how-to-configure-eclipse-build-path-to-use-maven-dependencies), you will achieve what you need: every external jar from an external (maven repo) URL will be download and taken into account by the Eclipse build path.

You can even [search for dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500141/find-a-jar-file-given-the-class-name/1500490#1500490) of any class you are using within your project.