# Find for a class file in Linux that is present in JAR

Tags: bash, unix, jar

I am trying to find a JAR file which contains my class using below command given in this link : [Find a jar file given the class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500141/find-a-jar-file-given-the-class-name)

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec sh -c 'jar -tf {}|grep -H --label {} GenericClassLoader' \;
```

but I am getting error as :

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:92)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.list(Main.java:997)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:242)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1167)
```

Please help me in understanding the command and also how solve this error. I am using bash shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something in your filesystem, which ends with `*.jar` but which isn't a valid archive. To debug this, add `-print` to the `find` command:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -print -exec ...
```

This will make `find` print the name of the file before it tries to execute the `sh` command.

Explanation:

- `find .`: Find all files and folder in the current directory
- `-name "*.jar"` whose name ends with `.jar`
- `-exec` and execute the following command for each of them
- `sh -c` Create a new shell and execute ...
- `jar -tf {}` Test a JAR archive. This (also) prints a list of files in the archive `find` will replace the `{}` with the path of the archive it found
- `|` pipe the result of `jar -tf` into ...
- `grep` search the input for ...
- `-H` Print the filename for each match
- `--label {}` Since we're reading from stdin, `grep` should use `{}` (again replaced by find) as the filename
- `GenericClassLoader` search for this string in the output of `jar -tf`

Comment: Thanks a lot Aaron, is there a way for hiding those error messages and displaying only correct output? I am able to find the jar file from the output but I have almost 100 error messages

Comment: Add `2>&/dev/null` between `{}` and `|`: `'jar -tf {} 2>&/dev/null | grep`

Comment: I think I am missing something here, I am using this command: `find . -name "*.jar" -exec sh -c 'jar -tf {} 2>&/dev/null |grep -H --label {} GenericClassLoader' \;` but I am getting error as `sh: /dev/null: ambiguous redirect` , please help me on this.

Comment: try `bash -c` instead of `sh -c`

Comment: I am getting same error, I am using this command : `find . -name "*.jar" -exec bash -c 'jar -tf {} 2>&/dev/null |grep -H --label {} GenericClassLoader' \;` , still I am getting error: `bash: /dev/null: ambiguous redirect`

Comment: :-/ it works for me (cut&paste). My guess is that you have odd file names. Really add `-print` to see for which files it prints errors. I think there are files with spaces in the name. if so use `"{}"` instead of `{}` (i.e. add quotes)

Comment: It is resolved now, after changing my command to `find . -name "*.jar" -exec bash -c 'jar -tf {} 2> /dev/null |grep -H --label {} GenericClassLoader' \; ` Thanks a lot for your continuous supprot.