# Getting /dev/null: ambiguous redirect error in unix

Tags: java, bash, unix, jar

I am using a shell script to find out files which contains a class file from a list of JAR files in UNIX using bash script:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec bash -c 'jar -tf {} |grep -H --label {} GenericClassLoader' \;
```

But I was getting error as :

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:92)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.list(Main.java:997)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:242)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1167)
```

I am taking help from this post : [Find for a class file in Linux that is present in JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356061/find-for-a-class-file-in-linux-that-is-present-in-jar/16356395#16356395)

In order to avoid the error I have modified my query as:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec bash -c 'jar -tf {} 2>&/dev/null |grep -H --label {} GenericClassLoader' \;
```

But I started getting below errors:

`bash: /dev/null: ambiguous redirect`

Please help me in solving this issue, what is the issue with my command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the redirection you wrote, you should redirect with `2> /dev/null` to send `stderr` to `/dev/null` (provided this is what you want).

Also note that you are not fixing the error, you are just preventing it to be visible.

For more details look here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html