# how to search for a package in jar using java program

Tags: java, jar

we have used bunch of  **jar files** in our maven spring application. Now my task is to

```
1. Find libraries used in our application in java.
2. then find jar file name, jar vendor, major version and minor version of jar for those used libraries in java.
```

fist one i,e Find libraries used in our application i did through j depend. now i have to do second task. I serached
stack overflow "[Find a class somewhere inside dozens of JAR files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342894/find-a-class-somewhere-inside-dozens-of-jar-files)" and other web search but couldn't able to achieve. can any one suggest me the way to do.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven `pom.xml` and its dependent .xml files can give you all the JAR files and preferably their versions too. From there it's just a question of extracting the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file to get the internal versioning of each file. You can do that with the `jar` tool.

Comment: I tried for using Jar tool but thing i didn't get is how to search for specific package in that jar....is there any code sample to discribe this