# Getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while executing my projects

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I am new to this office where I am doing my internship. They work with java web based frameworks like spring etc. As I was trying to set up my work-space I had to check out all their projects from the CVS repositories. Now when I try to execute it throws some exceptions:

The exceptions are listed below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1906)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:930)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:903)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.scraper.AgentLauncher.getDynamicContext(AgentLauncher.java:277)
    at com.scraper.AgentLauncher.main(AgentLauncher.java:652)
    at com.highradius.util.AgentLauncherTest.main(AgentLauncherTest.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: neet.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

The exceptions are also given in the below screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiD3s.png

Comment: I had very similar issue with terracota.
You need to check if there no two version of the same class in classpath.
Sometimes the same class can be included in librarry

Comment: Class JRException is not getting referred in your case..cross check your jars

Comment: are you using Maven for build? so can you please post the Maven build file?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer Yes I am using Maven for building. My work-space has more than 10 projects. Each of them have their own pom.xml file i.e their own maven build file . Which one do you want me to post ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly indicates

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: neet.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException
```

Just check once about this class in your classpath. Jar might be missing for it.

Comment: By what name should I search for the jar ? I mean I already have a few jars named similar to jasperreports. Please help.

Comment: This link might help you to find the required jar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342894/find-a-class-somewhere-inside-dozens-of-jar-files

Comment: Do a little check : Create a project in java eclipse , add all the jars that you are referencing ( i am assuming it is not more than 100) into the eclipse project. Press Ctrl+shift+T and then look for the neet.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException If you don't find any result it means you don't have jar there. If there are multiple result , you may want to remove some of the conflicting jars