# Steps For adding Apache Commons Codec into oracle database

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g, loadjava

I've the Apache common codecs library & I need to invoke that in the Oracle 11 database so I can create a java source that utilize the classes inside it as below.

What are the steps to make this library included in the database?

[image: Java file needs to be included in Oracle DB]

**Code need to achieved but giving symbol Can't be found

```
CREATE OR REPLACE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "org_apache_Base64" AS
import java.lang.*;
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; 

public class org_apache_Base64
{
  public static void ExportBlob(String CONTFILE, BLOB CONTBLOB) throws Exception
  {
  try
  {
    File file = new File("/u01/oracle/jam_export/contract1");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);  
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode("Test".getBytes());
    System.out.println("encodedBytes " + new String(encodedBytes));
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedBytes);
    System.out.println("decodedBytes " + new String(decodedBytes)); 
    System.out.println("PDF File Saved");
    fos.write(decoded); 
    fos.flush();
    fos.close(); 
    }
    catch  (Exception e) 
    {
     System.out.println(e); 
    }
  } };
```

Answer (score 0):

[Find the `jar` files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343026/1509264) containing those dependencies (which is probably downloadable from [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi)) and then use the [`loadjava` utility](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JJDEV/loadjava-tool.htm#JJDEV10060) to store them in the database so that Oracle can find them on its classpath.

```
loadjava -user USERNAME/PASSWORD@SID name_of_jar_file.jar
```

If you want to include the source files then you can also do that using `loadjava` but I would not recommend it for an external library as you would need to load **ALL** the dependencies for the `Base64.java` file and this may be hundreds (or thousands) of other source files; its easier just to find the JAR where these are packaged and load that one resource (or compile the source and package a JAR of it yourself).