Problem to resolve dependencies to external jars in oracle database ojvm
I tried to load a java program compiled with jdk 1.8 into an Oracle 19c database using loadjava.
They are dependencies on another jar but the dependencies are not resolved.
The compiled java sources outside the database works fine.
Any help would be appreciated!
I was building a testcase: Class with main method invokes other class in external jar.
Steps:

Generate jars with eclipse using: export->Runnable JAR file-> Package required libs into generated JAR -> gen.jar
Load it with loadjava -user test_usr/PWD@testdb -verbose -resolve -resolver "((* TEST_USR) (* PUBLIC))" gen.jar
In database the external.jar and the class are visible but the Main_class is invalid.
Compiling throws the error:


ORA-29521: referenced object de/externalLibrary/ExtClass could not be resolved

I tried several other loadjava options without success.
Any help would be appreciated!

You're saying java -jar gen.jar works without issue at the command line?

I understand that gen.jar also contains the external JAR. If that is correct, then I think you need to load the external JAR separately - via loadjava.

Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60074235/1509264 (i.e. work out what the external dependencies are and also load those into the database using the loadjava utility).
