# Apache Ignite Connector - Giving NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ignite, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to load kafka topic data into ignite caches with the help of Apache Ignite Sink connector. Facing following issue. All required jars are in place along with ignite configuration (xml) file.

I am pretty unsure why it is throwing ConnectException and NoClassDefFoundException for IgniteSinkTask$StreamerContext$Holder. Due to some reason java is unable to run these classes.

```
public static class StreamerContext {
    private StreamerContext() {
    }

    public static Ignite getIgnite() {
        return IgniteSinkTask.StreamerContext.Holder.IGNITE;
    }

    public static IgniteDataStreamer getStreamer() {
        return IgniteSinkTask.StreamerContext.Holder.STREAMER;
    }

    private static class Holder {
        private static final Ignite IGNITE;
        private static final IgniteDataStreamer STREAMER;

        private Holder() {
        }

        static {
            IGNITE = Ignition.start(IgniteSinkTask.igniteConfigFile);
            STREAMER = IGNITE.dataStreamer(IgniteSinkTask.cacheName);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

```
 [ERROR] 2021-08-27 06:13:58,827
 [task-thread-IgniteSinkConnectorConnector_0-0]
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask deliverMessages -
 WorkerSinkTask{​id=IgniteSinkConnectorConnector_0-0}​ Task threw an
 uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will
 not recover until manually restarted. Error: Could not initialize
 class
 org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkTask$StreamerContext$Holder
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
 org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkTask$StreamerContext$Holder
 at
 org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkTask$StreamerContext.getStreamer(IgniteSinkTask.java:198)
 at
 org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkTask.put(IgniteSinkTask.java:118)
 at
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:586)
 at
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:329)
 at
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
 at
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
 at
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
 at
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
 at
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
 at
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 at
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [ERROR] 2021-08-27
 06:13:58,828 [task-thread-IgniteSinkConnectorConnector_0-0]
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask doRun -
 WorkerSinkTask{​id=IgniteSinkConnectorConnector_0-0}​ Task threw an
 uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will
 not recover until manually restarted
 org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting
 WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception. at
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:614)
 at
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:329)
 at
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
 at
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
 at
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
 at
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
 at
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
 at
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
 at
 java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
 org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkTask$StreamerContext$Holder
 at
 org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkTask$StreamerContext.getStreamer(IgniteSinkTask.java:198)
 at
 org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkTask.put(IgniteSinkTask.java:118)
 at
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:586)
```

Comment: Show us the class in the error actually exists - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343026/2308683

Comment: Hi the class is part of kafka-ignite.2.9.1.jar, I have edited the problem. Please have a look and guide. Also, the error is popped only when I am trying to run it in distributed mode, in standalone it's not showing any such issue. Is it because of static nature of class?