# How can I accurately find out, which pom dependency?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm looking for a fool-proof method of finding the pom entry that will provide a project with a specific dependency. For example, if I have `import com.google.common.io.Files`, and it is not compiling because of a missing pom dependency entry, how can I find the specific dependency to add to my pom, with minimum fuss?

I know of the existence of `search.maven.org`, but sometimes that is unhelpful.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there isn't one. You need to know which library provides your dependency, and I'm not aware of a Maven search engine that indexes all files within the artifacts.

Comment: Related, and answers actually include answers to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342894/find-a-class-somewhere-inside-dozens-of-jar-files

Comment: I can confirm Mark, when you "mavenize" an existing project: google/search is your (only;(() friend. But most IDE's offer same/similar functionality as/to search.maven.org...commonly in the "add dependency dialog/frame".

Comment: On search.maven.org there is an enhanced search option to search on class base etc..??

Comment: For example, what could someone enter into a google search to find out the relevant info?

Comment: "fully qualified name", so "com.google.common.io.Files" in this case ..should guide you to correct GitHub/maven/site..then the "problem" is only to find the correct/appropriate version..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said, the search.maven.org is the best answer.

Comment: I will accept this, but there is an open source project in this for a student.